# AOSP overwrite Softkeyboard

Tags: android-source, soft-keyboard

I'd like to overwrite the AOSP keyboard with the google keyboard.

I am doing this because i dont want a settings icon on the keyboard.
Is there anyone who know where the keyboard files are located?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The IME (Input Method Manager) is located in `packages/inputmethods/LatinIME`.

You can either make your changes there, or you can fork the project. If you make your own project in the AOSP and you do not want to have both keyboards use `LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := LatinIME` in your `Android.mk` to exclude the LatinIME from the build.

If you have Google's IME prebuilt you can also create an `Android.mk` which installs the prebuilt APK and the particular shared object files (I think Google's IME comes with some shared objects) instead of building the LatinIME.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but i think it might be located in this dir:
*/aosp/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/inputmethod*

Check it out and tell me if you managed to overwrite it as wanted.

I have sources for Lollipop 5.01.